# how to find invalid dates in a leap year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well I have a table in sql and it contains date column with dates in it and I need to find invalid dates in a leap year e.g.
invalid dates i.e. 31st Feb. or 29th Feb. in a non leap year.

A simple query will help.

Comment: If you have a date column and its type is `datetime` then it cannot have invalid dates, as they are validated before being inserted.. other wise please state the format the dates have in your column

Comment: Yes it is datetime. so it means i already have the correct data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ISDATE function of sql server. Please refer: 
[ISDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx), 
[Validate DateTime String in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877434/validate-datetime-string-in-sql-server-2005)

Sample:

```
SELECT dt, ISDATE(dt) ValidDate
FROM(
    SELECT '31-Feb-2012' AS dt UNION
    SELECT '31-Jan-2012' AS dt 
)x
```

`ISDATE` returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.

You can check your existing table data using:

```
SELECT 
    date_of_birth, 
    ISDATE(date_of_birth) ValidDate 
FROM 
    YourTable
```

Comment: Sorry but can you please explain it further?

Comment: `ISDATE` returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0. Here '31-Feb-2012' returns 0 since it's an invalid date.

Comment: and how do i insert date_of_birth column in it? actually im new to sql

Comment: Please check the data using `SELECT date_of_birth, ISDATE(date_of_birth) ValidDT FROM YourTable`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - Question didn't mention about DBMS, tag specifies Ms-sql.

If you want to do it in `MySQL`:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('2012-02-29', INTERVAL 0 DAY);
+----------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('2012-02-29', INTERVAL 0 DAY) |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2012-02-29                             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-02-29', INTERVAL 0 DAY);
+----------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('2011-02-29', INTERVAL 0 DAY) |
+----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                   |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

For invalid date, `DATE_ADD` would return NULL. There could be other better ways.

Comment: Right, but I think question can also mention that, I don't think everybody takes a look at the tags before answering.

Answer (score 1):

A leap year can be determined by this :

```
 if year modulo 400 is 0 then
    is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0 then
   not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```